# Why is this regular expression failing to match the second 6 digit number?

Tags: regex, powershell

I can't understand why the following PowerShell is not working:

```
([regex]"(^|\D)(\d{6})(\D|$)").Matches( "123456 123457" ).Value
```

The code above code produces:

```
123456
```

Why is it not matching both numbers?

Comment: Did my answer work for  you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `"(^|\D)(\d{6})(\D|$)"` regex matches and  *consumes* a non-digit char before and after 6 digits (that is, the space after `123456` is consumed during the first iteration).

Use a *non-consuming* construct, lookbehind and lookahead:

```
"(?<!\d)\d{6}(?!\d)"
```

See a [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5Cd%29%5Cd%7B6%7D%28%3F!%5Cd%29&i=123456%20123457).

The `(?<!\d)` negative lookbehind fails the match if there is a digit immediately to the left of the current location and `(?!\d)` negative lookahead fails the match if there is a digit immediately after the current position, without actually moving the regex index inside the string.

Comment: So, if I have this right, what you are saying is that if not using lookbehind or lookahead, the starting point for the second match is the first character after the end of the first match. In my example my regex matches the whitespace on the first match so the second regex starts from 1.

Comment: Yes, the second match is searched for from `1` in `123457` "word".

Comment: PS code snippet: `$string -match '(?<!\d)\d{6}(?!\d)' | Out-Null`, then use `$matches[0]` to access the match value.